# Is there a way to access Omni-Channel Methods for Lightning Console without creating a Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, omnichannel

I was looking through Salesforce Console Developer Guide for [Methods for Omni-Channel in Lightning Experience](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.212.0.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_omnichannel_methods.htm). Does anyone know of a way of access these methods without creating aura components?

Answer (score 0):

Visualforce is available in Lightning console apps as beta,  therefore, you could use the [Methods for Omni-Channel](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_omnichannel_methods.htm) that are not specific to lightning.

and while you are at it, you might want to check [Lightning Experience Console Limitations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=console_lex_limitations.htm&type=5)